# Can MOOCs Count towards the GISP course points?

Tags: education, certification, gis-professional

I am looking to obtain my GISP, and I am wondering if Massive Open Online Course (MOOCs)  can count towards the GISP course points if the MOOC is related to GIS?

Answer (score 6):

It will be up to the committee upon submittal.
It must follow the documented credential outlined in the EDU section of the GISP [step by step instructions](http://www.gisci.org/Portals/0/PDF's/Application%20Step%20by%20Step%20%20Instructions%20Power%20Point%20Education%20Section.pptx) ( The link is to a powerpoint from the [GISCI](http://www.gisci.org/Applicants/ApplicationsMaterials.aspx) website).
Page 6 and page 14-15 outline the minimums to meet.
page 16-22 help with calculating points for accredited edu. 
Page 23 has guidance for vague courses.